# Unroot Galaxy Note 5 SM-N902i (XSA Australia) with Heimdall - "System UI has stopped"

Tags: rom-flashing, linux, unrooting, heimdall, samsung-galaxy-note-5

I am running a linux machine and trying to unroot my Galaxy Note 5. I've downloaded the lastest firmware from sammobile: N920IDVU4CRG1_N920IXSA4CRG1_XSA.zip which extracts to:
`boot.img
cache.img
cm.bin
hidden.img
modem.bin
recovery.img
sboot.bin
system.img`

Then I've been trying to use heimdall like so:

`heimdall flash --verbose --BOOTLOADER sboot.bin --CM cm.bin --BOOT boot.img --RECOVERY recovery.img --RADIO modem.bin --SYSTEM system.img --CACHE cache.img --HIDDEN hidden.img`

The process finishes successfully but then when the phone reboots it hangs with an error: "**System UI has stopped**"

I've previously executed heimdall print-pit to check the pit list. I noticed that there are more pit entries than the 8 provided in the firmware. I don't know if that's normal.
I also tried using the pit file found on the forum with the same negative result: [NOBLELTE_AUS_XSA.pit](https://www.sammobile.com/forum/threads/30106-galaxy-note-5-(-N920-)-pit-files)

`heimdall flash --pit NOBLELTE_AUS_XSA.pit --verbose --BOOTLOADER sboot.bin --CM cm.bin --BOOT boot.img --RECOVERY recovery.img --RADIO modem.bin --SYSTEM system.img --CACHE cache.img --HIDDEN hidden.img`

Same error.

Is there something that I've been missing or done wrong?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The problems exists in the system.img. It might have been comiled with a corrupted systemUI.apk. Try other flashable files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried other flashables files but the results was the same.
I flashed twrp using adb, and realised there was some of my data left on the phone. So I deleted it all using twrp. Then I used heimdall again to flash the firmware and it worked!
Odin gives exactly the same results.